# Code gives me incorrect result in C

Tags: c

can someone explain to me why this code prints the decremented amount? Since (4 <= 3) is false, shouldn't it proceed to print "Hi"?

```
int main()
{
    int amount = 4;

    if((amount%5) <= (--amount))
        printf("%d", amount);
    else
        printf("Hi");
}
```

Comment: Hello undefined behavior...

Comment: I don't think the question should have been downvoted. The person is obviously new to programming and is learning. It was an honest mistake for the person and just as @SteveSummit put it: *You might think the code has to be evaluated left-to-right...  But that's not the way it works.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this code is *undefined*.  You've got the expression

```
(amount%5) <= (--amount)
```

But the key question is, does the `amount%5` part use the old value of `amount`, or the new, after being decremented by the `--amount` part?  And the answer is: *We have no idea. There's no way to tell.  There's no rule in the C language to tell us.*

You might think the code has to be evaluated left-to-right, that the `amount%5` part has to happen first, before the `--amount` part has a chance to happen.  But that's not the way it works.  Since it's undefined, anything could happen.

*If* it's evaluated more or less left-to-right, then we have

```
if(amount%5 <= --amount)
```

which evaluates to

```
if(4%5 <= --amount)
```

which evaluates to

```
if(4 <= --amount)
```

which evaluates to

```
if(4 <= 3)
```

which is false, so you might expect it to print "Hi".  *But*, if it's evaluated more or less right-to-left, it's

```
if(amount%5 <= 3)
```

which evaluates to

```
if(3%5 <= 3)
```

which evaluates to

```
if(3 <= 3)
```

which is true.

(You'll notice that I have removed some extra parentheses, since they don't do anything.)

I hasten to add that these are *not* the only two possibilities.  The rules say that once an expression is undefined, literally *anything* can happen -- the behavior doesn't have to be anything we might consider "reasonable" at all.

So why is it undefined?  In this case it's because you have a variable -- `amount` -- which appears twice in the expression, and where one of those appearances is a modification (the `--amount` part), and where the other one uses the variable's value.  The C Standard explicitly tells us that in this case (a) we can't tell whether the use of `amount` uses the old or the modified value, and furthermore that (b) this flaw in the expression -- this simultaneous modification and use -- renders the whole expression (and actually the whole program it's in) undefined.

So how do you fix it?  The answer is simple, and it's the punchline of an old joke: *Don't do that*.  Don't write expressions where a single variable (or other object) is both modified and used.  It's fine to write `--amount`, just don't do it in an expression that's also using the value of the variable `amount` somewhere else.

Questions like this come up often.  The canonical SO answers, which others are already redirecting you to, are collected under the question [Why are these constructs (using ++) undefined behavior in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/).  There's more I could say about the rules concerning undefined expressions, but you can find those details over at that question.

Comment: Awesome explanation! You made a lot of awesome edits since I last read your answer! +1